# DriveApp.searchFiles - how to use wildcard in readers field?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to search for all files in a Shared Drive that are shared outside the domain with ordinary GMail accounts.

I first tried this:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('readers contains "@gmail.com"');
```

But this produces an error when I try to use the returned value:

```
Exception: Invalid argument: q
```

I went back and reviewed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms) and noticed that only the `in` operator is "valid" for the `readers` query term.

However, the documentation is very vague about how to use the `in` operator either.  For instance, I tried this:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('readers in [ "somebody@gmail.com" ]');
```

and I get the same error as above! The documentation for the "in operator" only says `An element is contained within a collection.` but it does not explain what a collection is.

So my main question is how I can do a wildcard search to basically find all files that have been shared with (are readable by) any ordinary @gmail.com account, but if that is not possible, how to properly phrase the search when I have to manually provide the list, given that I would have around a hundred different addresses to search in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('readers in [ "somebody@gmail.com" ]');
```

#### To:

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"somebody@gmail.com" in readers'); // or var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("'somebody@gmail.com' in readers");
```

- or `'readers in "somebody@gmail.com"'`, `"readers in 'somebody@gmail.com'"`.
- If you want to search multiple email addresses, please use

  ```
    "'somebody1@gmail.com' in readers or 'somebody2@gmail.com' in readers"
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files)

Comment: @Michael By the way, if you don't want to include the files in the trash box in the retrieve file list, please add a query of `trashed=false` to the search query.